# Bluetooth mouse does not work in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, mouse, bluetooth

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04 and the Bluetooth mouse does not work. I put in new batteries and search for bluetooth devices in Systems Setting; it constantly comes for a moment and then disappears. Mouse light flashes for few seconds on when it's turned on, but then it goes off. Restarted several times.

"hctool scan" finds nothing. "hcitool dev" finds something, but the address is different from what comes for a second when I search for bluetooth in systems setting. I set AutoconnectTimeout=0 in /etc/bluetooth/main.conf, nothing happened.

I am not sure if this a bug in 14.04. Please help if you have any idea.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. I found a solution that works for the 14.04 Ubuntu on my MacMini listed underneath related over in the right hand margin of the "Questions" page. I mated my mouse with a different computer, then thru the command key tap, in the next window arrow down until you get to the tool bar at the bottom of the window, Right arrow to the Apps Icon, "Enter" to select, on the next page manuever to the bluetooth icon, in the next window "Tab" until you highlight the "+" button, hit "Enter", turn your mouse on and its at this point my Logitech Travel mouse was recognized. Follow the prompts from there. Good luck.